# When I use ViewModel.Factory, appear `Kodein No binding found for bind<Kodein>()` error

Tags: android, kodein

I reference to http://kodein.org/Kodein-DI/?6.1/android#view-model-factory use the kodein viewmodel, appeared the error.

the part code

```
bind<ViewModelProvider.Factory>() with singleton { KodeinViewModelFactory(instance()) }
```

```
class KodeinViewModelFactory(private val kodein: Kodein) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

  override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
      kodein.direct.Instance(TT(modelClass))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple, you just need to directly transfer Kodein to the factory, without instance()

```
class KodeinApp : Application(), KodeinAware {
    override val kodein by Kodein.lazy {
    import(androidXModule(this@KodeinApp))
    bind() from singleton { KodeinViewModelFactory(kodein) }
    bind() from singleton { MyViewModel(kodein) }
    }
}
```